# tkinter treeview horizontal scrollbar not working when columns is resized

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1280x720')
        self.tv = ttk.Treeview(self)
        columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H')
        self.tv.config(columns=columns, show='headings')
        for col in columns:
            self.tv.column(col)
            self.tv.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.W)
        scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.tv.yview)
        scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.tv.xview, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tv.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)
        scrollbar_y.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
        scrollbar_x.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.tv.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

Application().mainloop()
```

Problem:

Initially, the horizontal scrollbar can show can work properly. As shown in the screen capture below.
[image]

But once I try to resize any one of the columns, the horizontal scrollbar disappear. It tries to squeeze all columns inside the window. As shown below.
[image]

May I ask how can I make it to keep the horizontal scrollbar stay here, even though I have resized some of the columns?

(I have tried to set `minwide` for all columns, but it will make them unable to resize.)

Test platform:
Windows 11,
Tkinter 8.6,
Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason of this behaviour. This is not a bug. It can be fix by adding an argument to `tv.column()`.

`stretch=False` should be added as shown below:

```
[...]
for col in columns:
    self.tv.column(col, stretch=False)
    self.tv.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.W)
[...]
```

Originally, I thought `stretch` is for allowing the column to be resized or not. But I found that it actually means:

> If this option is True, the column's width will be adjusted when the widget is resized.

from the documentation [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html#:%7E:text=If%20this%20option%20is%20True%2C%20the%20column%27s%20width%20will%20be%20adjusted%20when%20the%20widget%20is%20resized.%20The%20default%20setting%20is%201.).

Hope this can helps who is confusing about the issue as I am.

Answer (score 0):

> But once I try to resize any one of the columns, the horizontal
> scrollbar disappear. It tries to squeeze all columns inside the window.

Your code is working.

If the  dictionary(`columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H')`) is reduced,  the horizontal will disappear even if you resize.

Or, you can move any `Treeview` columns to right. The horizontal will not disappear.

If the  dictionary (`columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O')`) is increased,  the horizontal will not disappear even if you resize.